# Trying to convert JS && operator function to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have JS code which I am trying to convert to C#. For some reason my C# method is returning 10 less than the return value of the JS function. I have tried changing multiple things and also checking the meaning of the `&&` operator in JS but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

The correct return value is 97.

JavaScript Function & Usage:

```
function rir(t, e, c, n) {
    return t > e 
        && t <= c 
        && (t += n % (c - e)) > c 
        && (t = t - c + e),
       t
}
rir('a'.charCodeAt(0), 47, 57, 'b'.charCodeAt(0));
/* returns 97 */
```

C# Method & Usage:

```
public int Rir(int t, int e, int c, int n)
{
    if (t > e && t <= c)
        t += (n % (c - e));
    if (t > c)
        t = ((t - c) + e);
    return t;
}
Rir((int)'a', 47, 57, (int)'b');
/* returns 87 */
```

Comment: Those single-letter variable names and assignments in the middle of expressions definitely don't help readability. Oh dear

Comment: I don't know very much about JavaScript, this JavaScript function was pre written and also most likely was minified (guessing by the terrible naming convention). I am just trying to copy it over to C# verbatim.

Comment: @kingdaro I was thinking the same thing. Whoever wrote that needs to be punched in the face.

Comment: @Darkrum Like OP says, it's _probably_ minified, but I still wouldn't be surprised if it were handwritten. Seen some shit, haha

Comment: Note that `'a'` is a JavaScript `string` but a C# `char`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(t = t - c + e)` requires the first three condition to be true.

```
public int Rir(int t, int e, int c, int n)
{
    if (t > e && t <= c)
    {
        t += (n % (c - e));
        if (t > c)
            t = ((t - c) + e);
    }
    return t;
}
```